# Avoid destruction of an object in c++

Tags: c++

Hello everyone this is my first time here
How can I avoid the destruction of an object in C++
I want to keep the informations of the object so I can display them using another function

Comment: It depends. Without knowing exactly what you are doing, all we can offer are suggestions.

Comment: I think you have an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: You need to learn about scoping and how/when automatic variables are destroyed.  You have a lot of control over the scoping of your objects.  For example, this "other function" you are talking about means that you need your object lifetime to exceed the scope of the original.  Instead of this object being local, can it be instantiated by the CALLer of (both) functions, and passed as parameters.  Or is it possibly a state variable of the object doing the CALLing, so it needs to be a member variable?

Answer (score 4):

There is generally no need to *entirely* "avoid" the destruction of any object. What you should do instead, is to keep the object alive at least as long as its "information" is being used. Once it's no longer used, it is good to let the object be destroyed.

> I want to keep the informations of the object so I can display them using another function

You should probably return the object from the function so that it can be used on the outside of that function. Example:

```
struct Example {
    int information:
};

Example make_information() {
    Example e;
    e.information = 42;
    return e;
}

void display_information(const Example& example) {
    std::cout << example.information;
}

int main() {
    Example ex = make_information();
    display_information(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with pointers ?

In C++ you can use pointers to pass datas between functions (without making a copy)

The old way:

```
int* myInt = new int(100);

myAwesomeFunction(myInt);

delete myInt;
```

The new way (C++11)

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = new int(100);
```

Even better (C++14)

```
auto myVal = make_unique<int>(100);
```

In the two last ways the object are automatically destroyed at end of program (Edit: when the pointer is destroyed manually or out of scope). In the first one you have to destruct the object yourself !

Comment: I've made an edit thanks for the comment, you're totally right I was a bit too easy on this one but i think if the author don't know pointers he must check for pointers with mode details